# How quickly is she running towards the exit? = How fast is she running towards the exit?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

What is the difference in meaning between
***How quickly is she running towards the exit?***
and
***How fast is she running towards the exit?***

Is the following dialogue ok:

***- How soon can she drive here?***

***- She will drive here very fast.***

Comment: No, it sounds non-native. There's nothing wrong with it technically, it's just OFF.

Comment: "Quickly" is an adverb. "Fast" is an adjective. Your sentence requires an adverb. Your dialogue requires two. She herself may be fast and her car may be fast but we run and drive quickly.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian *Fast* has always been an adverb in English. It used to be spelt faste, but the *e* got dropped along with the change in pronunciation. Unlike many flat adverbs, there is no alternative form with an *-ly*, and it is somewhat restricted in use compared to modern -ly adverbs. (Fast, I ran to the phone*)

Answer (score 2):

***Quickly*** is not usually used with vehicles that run at a high speed, like cars, trains etc. Here is what [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/fast-quick-or-quickly) says about **fast** and **quick/quickly**:

> We usually use ***quick*** to refer to something happening in a short time,
> or a shorter than expected time:
>
> - We stopped for a ***quick*** snack. (**NOT**: … a fast snack.)
> - I just need a ***quick*** answer. (**NOT**: … a fast answer.)
>
> ***Fast*** refers to things that happen or go at high speed, e.g. a train, a
> person running:
>
> - She loves ***fast*** cars. (**NOT**: She loves quick cars.)

So we say for example, "She is a ***fast runner/fast driver***", (not a quick driver). However, [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drive%20fast%2C%20drive%20quickly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrive%20fast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrive%20quickly%3B%2Cc0) does find some instances of "drive quickly", but the phrase is much less frequent than "drive fast".

As for your dialogue, it does sound off. Instead of "How soon can she drive here?", I would say "How fast can she get here?". And the more natural answer would be: "In no time! She is a fast driver."

Comment: Wondering why it is _fast food_ instead of _quick food_ then? Good answer, by the way.

Comment: @user405662: Have a look at the link from Cambridge I gave. It says: "Note the common expression **fast food** to refer to food such as hamburgers, which are cooked and served in a very short time in restaurants."

Comment: Indeed, the cooking itself may take a minute, but if there is a long queue of orders, it may take ten minutes for it to be actually served.

Comment: @Ruralguy: I don't think that would entitle us to call it "slow food" though :-) !